# How does Spring inject list as constructor argument

Tags: java, spring

**I've got** this:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class MyDefaultDef {

  @Inject
  public MyDefaultDef(SomeRef someRef, List<AnotherRef> anotherRefs) {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

**Question1: [main]** *How does work autowiring of `List<AnotherRef> anotherRefs` as a constructor arg?*

I mean if I'd like to replace that bean definition with xml, I had to specify each element of the list. I.e.

```
<constructor-arg>
  <list> 
     <ref bean="..."/>
     <ref bean="..."/>
  </list> 
</constructor-arg>
```

But from where Spring takes those elements in case of annotations?

**Question2:** *How to replace `MyDefaultDef` bean definition to xml?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Spring needs to autowire a `List<SomeBean>`, it looks up all beans in its `BeanFactory` and retrieves all those that are of type `SomeBean`. It thens creates a `List` and adds them to it. It then autowires it.

There is no way in Spring XML to do this listing by type. You'll need to compromise. You leave your class as such

```
public class MyDefaultDef {

    @Inject
    public MyDefaultDef(SomeRef someRef, List<AnotherRef> anotherRefs) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

and simply declare

```
<bean class="com.example.MyDefaultDef" autowire="constructor"/>
```

Spring will end up using your constructor above.